# Including transient dependencies with Gradle Module Metadata

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, maven-publish

I've run into an issue while using the `maven-publish` plugin for this Android library I'm developing. I've looked at similar posts on SO and other forums as well, and my issue is still persisting.

**scenario:**

> I have `Library A` which includes the core of the library, `Library B` which is a wrapper around `Library A`. So `B` depends on `A`. `B` also has several other dependencies on its own.

**issue:**

> I need to be able to include only `Library B` and have all the required (api/compile) transient dependencies be downloaded along with it.

**what i've tried**:

> (1) I read up [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency_configurations) on how Gradle populates the generated `pom.xml` file with the dependencies required by looking at the dependencies you've declared in the `dependencies {}` block. **api** means the dependency should be transient and **implementation** hides it (prevents leakage). So I went ahead and applied the changes needed to `Library B`'s gradle.build and marked all the dependencies I wanted with api. This did not work and the generated `pom.xml` still did not contain the transient deps.

> (2) I've followed the steps [here](https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2015/08/13/artifactory2/) and thought it's now generating the `pom.xml` with all the dependencies, after publishing it to mavenLocal and attempting to consume it in a fresh Demo app the project is building but it crashes as soon as it attempts to run (due to the missing dependencies).

**code:**

```
pom.withXml {
    // for dependencies and exclusions
    def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

    //Iterate over the compile dependencies (we don't want the test ones), adding a <dependency> node for each
    configurations.api.allDependencies.each { dp ->
        def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', dp.group)
        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', dp.name)
        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', dp.version)
        // for exclusions
        if (dp.excludeRules.size() > 0) {
            def exclusions = dependencyNode.appendNode('exclusions')
            dp.excludeRules.each { ExcludeRule ex ->
                def exclusion = exclusions.appendNode('exclusion')
                exclusion.appendNode('groupId', ex.group)
                exclusion.appendNode('artifactId', ex.module)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

The only way I've gotten it to work so far was by also adding all the other deps on top of `Library B` (needless to say this is not ideal...)

**QUESTION:** How can I achieve what I need while only adding this one library?

Answer (score 0):

After getting some much needed sleep I saw the world (Google) with a fresh pair of eyes and stumbled upon the following notation:

```
implementation ('Library B') {
    transitive = true // this tells your gradle to fetch the transient dependencies related to 'Library B'
}
```

---

Note: If your dependency needs the `@aar` at the end of it (specifies only the .aar artifact should be downloaded), then by default you will not get any transient dependencies of that library, in which case you would need the solution I stated above. Otherwise, you can omit the `transitive = true` and as long as the dependencies are written to the publication `pom.xml` file prior to publishing it you should get all the transients.

After applying this everything is back to working as expected, thought I did read that Gradle **defaults** this `transitive` property to true... so I'm still confused as to why I needed to specify it.